# is there an 'upwards' find?

Tags: linux, shell, find, path

I found I asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/412451/62815) on the wrong stackexchange site.

To find files starting from a certain path, I can use `find <path> ...`.  If I want to find 'upwards', i.e. in the parent directory, and it's parent, and..., is there an equivalent tool?

The use case is knowing the right number of dots (../../x.txt or ../../../x.txt?) to use in e.g. a makefile including some common makefile functions somewhere upstream.

Intended usage for a folder structure like this:

```
/
/abc
/abc/dce/efg/ghi
/abc/dce/efg2


$ cd /abc/dce/efg/ghi
$ touch ../../x.txt
$ upfind . -name X*
../../x.txt
$ upfind . -name Y* || echo "not found"
not found
$ touch /abc/dce/efg2/x.txt
$ upfind . -name Y* || echo "not found"
not found
$
```

So in short:

- it should search on this folder, it's parent, it's parent's parent...
- but not in any of their siblings (like 'find' would)
- it should report the found file(s) relative to the current path

Comment: It appears from the link that you already wrote a script that solved your problem...

Comment: @Matt: yes, but I'm allways try to find one better answer, and this is a better forum to do so.

Comment: Ah. Actually, I would think the best forum would be SO, wouldn't it?

Comment: Possible same on unix SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/find-searching-in-parent-directories-instead-of-subdirectories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing answers unsufficient (details below).

Put this into a script named `upfind` somewhere in your `$PATH`, and `chmod +x /the/path/upfind`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DIR=$(readlink -f "$1")
# Alternative: use current working dir; but then also replace ${@:2} with $@ on line 8
# and $1 with $PWD when calling realpath
# DIR=$PWD

while
  RESULT=$(find "$DIR"/ -maxdepth 1 "${@:2}")
  # echo "Debugging upfind - search in $DIR gives: $RESULT"
  [[ -z $RESULT ]] && [[ "$DIR" != "/" ]]
do DIR=$(dirname "$DIR"); done

realpath --relative-to="$1" "$RESULT"
# Alternative: output absolute path
# echo "$RESULT"
```

The two alternatives you might consider can be toggled in the script; using $PWD instead of the first parameter means we need to pass $@ (all parameters) to find, and outputting the full path instead of a relative path by commenting the realpath line and just echoing $RESULT.

Note use of a do-while loop is from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24421013/2144408).

Choroba and Matthew Wolff got the end condition wrong; so they would fail to find a file that is actually in the root of the filesystem. They also both do cd's, which is not something I want bash scripts to do. Peter O's solution looks better, but simply outputs nothing for my constructed testcase, and it's easier to write a new bash script than to debug an existing one.

Comment: Thanks!  Indeed, avoiding `cd` allows one to reuse this snippet inside another bash script (or a function).

We have to start providing test suites for our snippets, as a community, I mean.  That would have revealed the `/needle` edge case early.

Answer (score 23):

You can use this simple script. It walks the directory tree upwards and searches for the specified files.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
prev=.
while [[ $PWD != "$prev" ]] ; do
    find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 "$@"
    prev=$PWD
    cd ..
done
```

Usage:

```
upfind -name 'x*'
```

Comment: Without having tested it, doesn't this print an incrementally growing result list with duplicates because the loop terminates when root is reached?

Comment: Why the loop termination at the root should result in duplicates?

Comment: Hm okay: I was wrong with the duplicates because I didn't consider the `-maxdepth` flag when I said that. I was also under the impression that we want to stop searching after the first match, and this script doesn't do that – it runs `find` on each iteration until we reach the root. I treated this problem more like `.closest()` in jQuery. But no, `upfind` should behave like you suggested. Never mind me.

Comment: Grave digging... but @tamaMcGlinn rightfully pointed out that this script doesn't find needles that are in the root directory.

Comment: @xtofl: Updated.

Comment: I see the update, but read OP's question carefully; your new script gives an error for the stated use-case: "find: paths must precede expression: `.'"

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn: Have you read the whole post and have you used the `-name` argument?

Comment: Look under 'intended usage': `$ upfind . -name X*` should give: `../../x.txt` for the example folder structure. Because your variant passes a path already, you don't use that first parameter. The idea is that you are in a directory with a makefile, and you want the path to another makefile which must be somewhere above directory X (in the example, he happens to use . but any directory should work). I guess it was easy for me at the time because I had the exact same use-case as OP myself.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. If you want to pass a path as the first parameter, prepend `cd "$1" ; shift` to the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can just split the path into its constituent directory nodes and search each one discreetly. It is a `bash` script.

```bash
IFS=/; dn=($1); ct=${#dn[@]}
for((i=0; i<ct; i++)); do
  subd+=/"${dn[i]}"
  dots=$(for((j=ct-i; j>1; j--)); do printf "../"; done)
  find "$subd" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$2" -printf "$dots%f\n"
done
```

run `upfind $HOME/zt" "Y*"` ... which produces the following output
when *YABBA* exists in */*, */home/user*,  */home/user/zt*

```
../../../YABBA
../YABBA
YABBA
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for something similar but more concise for interactive shell

### Bash

You can define a short recursive function:

```
upfind () {
  ls -d $1 || upfind ../$1
}
```

### Zsh

A one-liner is possible. Unfortunately, you'll need to manually press Enter a few times.

```
ls -d ./.git || pushln '^./^./../^'
```

`pushln` makes `^./^./../^` be waiting for you in your next prompt which in turn expands into the same command but with added `../`

Comment: Thanks!  That's nifty!  Redirecting to /dev/null makes it a bit nicer.  It needs an end condition, too: the bash version recurses infinitely when needle is not found.

Comment: Replacing the else-branch with `([ "$(realpath $(dirname $1))" == "/" ] || upfind ../$1;)` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @choroba's answer with my own solution for finding the upward location of a file (by name):

```bsh
upfind() {
  ORIG_DIR="$PWD"
  while [[ "$PWD" != / ]] ; do
    if find "$PWD"/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$@" | grep -q "$@"; then
      echo "$PWD" && builtin cd "$ORIG_DIR"
      return 0
    else
      builtin cd ..
    fi
  done
  builtin cd "$ORIG_DIR"
  return 1
}
```

Example:

```
> upfind packageInfo
/home/matthew/development/packageRoot
```

It will return with an error code, which is useful if you're using it in a conditional. However, this solution is less of an upward version of `find` (I assume it won't play nice when you pass in additional parameters) as it is a specific solution to finding a file by name.

Answer (score 0):

Bash function.

- doesn't change directory
- doesn't use subshells
- doesn't use ls
- doesn't use find
- sets the exit code if the file is not found.

```
upfind()
{
# work with full path for search
local search ; [[ ${1:0:1} == "/" ]] && search="$1" || search="$PWD/$1" ;

# does the searched file exist
stat "$search" &>/dev/null && echo "$search" ||
    {
    # file not found, try parent's directory
 
    # split the search in its components 
    local path="${search%/*}" file="${search##*/}" parent_path="${path%/*}"

    # if there's a parent, try to find the searched file there
    [[ "$parent_path" ]] && upfind "$parent_path/$file"
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?